# Qual o correto: "daqui para frente" ou "daqui para a frente"?

Tags: expressões, expressões-equivalentes

Fiz esta busca e achei que as duas formas são largamente empregadas.

Estão ambas corretas? Ou alguma delas está incorreta?

Comment: No Brasil, na linguagem falada, distingue-se *para a frente* de *para frente* ou só se distingue na escrita?

Comment: @Jacinto No Brasil, fala-se "pra", que pode significar tanto "para", quanto "para a", mesmo em contextos muito formais, como no Congresso ou em fóruns de justiça.

Comment: @Ramon, sim, mas se pronunciares mesmo *para a frente* e *para frente*? Ficam iguais?

Comment: @Jacinto Sim. O ritmo dos sotaques brasileiros que eu conheço não me permite distinguir entre ambas as formas. Se existe alguma distinção, parece-me reservada à língua escrita.

Comment: @Ramon, Vem provavelmente daí. Em Portugal só se usa *para a frente*, e na fala nota-se a presença ou ausência do ***a*** mesmo que reduzas o *para* a *pra* ou mesmo a *pa*.

Comment: @RamonMelo   Sim, em português falado usamos muito "pra frente" e não há como saber se há um artigo embutido.  Na letra da música de Roberto Carlos não há o artigo ("daqui pra frente, tudo vai ser diferente")

Comment: Independente de estar certo ou errado, se eu tivesse que transcrever a fala de alguém, eu possivelmente não colocaria o artigo em "daqui pra frente".

Comment: Apenas minha interpretação não há nenhum fundamento técnico. Percebo ambos de formas diferentes, em "daqui para frente" parece algo que irá seguir indefinidamente como "daqui em diante" ou "a partir de agora". No outro caso "daqui para a frente" parece um deslocamento de uma posição para outra como "[mova-se] daqui para a frente [do palco]".

Answer (score 2):

Segundo "Manual de Comunicação" do Senado Federal:

> Na expressão, o substantivo frente pede artigo. Use "para a frente".

Mais detalhes: https://www12.senado.leg.br/manualdecomunicacao/redacao-e-estilo/estilo/para-a-frente

Comment: Só uma observação: o manual do Senado só tem papel normativo para os órgãos filiados ao próprio Senado.

Comment: Concordo com @RamonMelo.   Existem fontes bem mais abrangentes.

Comment: é só colocar as outras fontes. O objetivo aqui é dar a resposta certa.

Comment: Não encontrei nenhuma fonte que me convencesse. Permaneço com a dúvida do Ítalo. Mas a questão que eu e o @Centaurus levantamos não é esta. O Senado tem o direito de estabelecer as regras estilísticas que desejar, mesmo que destoem do convencional. Por exemplo, ele sugere [Fifa](https://www12.senado.leg.br/manualdecomunicacao/redacao-e-estilo/estilo/fifa), [regras complexas citar cidades](https://www12.senado.leg.br/manualdecomunicacao/redacao-e-estilo/estilo/cidade), e uma [longa lista de como citar os senadores](https://www12.senado.leg.br/manualdecomunicacao/como-citar-os-senadores-pdf).

Comment: idem............

Answer (score 1):

O [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/para-a-frente-e-para-cima/28628) alega que "daqui para a frente" é o uso correto:

> Embora quer frente quer cima sejam substantivos, a ocorrência em locuções adverbiais faz-se num caso com artigo («para a frente») e noutro sem artigo («para cima»). A única resposta possível nestas situações é aceitar esta diferença como resultado de processos de fixação (lexicalização) de certas expressões como locuções adverbiais.

Mas o Ciberdúvidas não tem nenhum valor normativo, e, convenhamos, um argumento que precisa sugerir "aceitar esta diferença", por si só, não me parece convincente.

O dicionário português [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/frente%20afrente) também prefere "daqui para a frente":

> daqui para a frente
>
> • A partir deste ponto no tempo ou no espaço

O brasileiro [Aurélio](https://contas.tcu.gov.br/dicionario/home.asp) adota uma posição parecida:

> Ir para a frente: Progredir, prosperar.

Dicionários, especialmente os mais populares, têm um valor normativo significativo. A expressão "daqui para a frente" é decididamente *correta*. Porém, o gênero textual dos dicionários não permite muito espaço para justificativas, e nenhum deles responde se "daqui para frente" está *incorreta*.

A imprensa, especialmente a brasileira, também prefere o uso do artigo, mas possui numerosos exemplos de "daqui para frente":

> Estadão: [Eficiência é a palavra daqui para frente](http://educacao.estadao.com.br/blogs/ana-maria-diniz/eficiencia-e-a-palavra-daqui-para-frente/)
>
> Valor Econômico: [Petrobras vê mercado mais volátil 'daqui para frente' com Trump](http://www.valor.com.br/empresas/4773285/petrobras-ve-mercado-mais-volatil-daqui-para-frente-com-trump) (note a crítica sutil que o jornal faz ao termo, porém)
>
> The Huffington Post Brasil: [O que queremos daqui para frente?](http://www.huffpostbrasil.com/tayna-leite/queremos-futuro_b_9498480.html)
>
> SporTV: [Camilo comemora vitória: "Daqui para frente é fazer da Arena nossa força"](http://sportv.globo.com/futebol-nacional/videos/v/camilo-comemora-vitoria-daqui-para-frente-e-fazer-da-arena-nossa-forca/5202329/)

Os [livros no catálogo do Google Books](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=%22daqui%20para%20frente%22&tbm=bks&tbs=sbd:1) com o termo sem artigo também são abundantes, mas, dos 170 resultados datados, somente 15 foram publicados nos séculos XIX e XX. Isto sugere que a disseminação de "daqui para frente" é bastante recente na língua portuguesa (e, aparentemente, ainda restrita às variações brasileiras). Como as normas da língua tendem a se adaptar ao uso efetivo da língua, talvez estejamos no processo de *gramaticalização* desta expressão, e ela venha a se tornar aceita pela norma culta.

Enquanto isto, eu sugiro o uso da expressão com artigo ("daqui para a frente") se você precisar se enquadrar na norma culta (por exemplo, em redações de concursos públicos).

Comment: O artigo do Ciberdúvidas, mesmo sendo uma resposta a um leitor brasileiro, simplesmente descreve o uso em Portugal. Em Portugal, mesmo na fala, distingue-se *para a frente* de *para frente*, mesmo quando *para* se reduz a *pra* ou a *pa*, o que provavelmente ajudou a fixar a escrita.

Comment: Tu já tens *para frente* na literatura brasileira do sXIX, mas *para a frente* vence *para frente* 6 a 1 (vê [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/), e alguns *para frente* parecem erros, como, num guião de teatro, "avança para frente do palco", por exemplo.

Comment: @Jacinto Eu até acho o uso em Portugal válido para decisões sobre o português empregado no Brasil, mas o Ciberdúvidas, na minha opinião, ficou devendo na argumentação.

Comment: Precisamente, voltei a ler o artigo, e o autor limita-se a dizer "ocorrência em locuções adverbiais faz-se num caso com artigo («para a frente»)", esquecendo-se de dizer que isto é assim em Portugal. Aplicando o mesmo "argumento" ao Brasil, no Brasil escreve-se *para frente* e *para a frente*, logo estão ambos corretos.

Comment: @Jacinto Engraçado como a mesma premissa gera conclusões diametralmente opostas. Mas eu sou contra mesmo assim. Se é para legitimar um uso, que se legitime o uso de "daqui pra frente", que já está sendo falado e escrito há séculos em todos os dialetos nacionais.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não tenho certeza se você está se referindo a o Português Brasileiro ou de Portugal, de qualquer forma, no Brasileiro, tanto a pronúncia quanto a escrita são: **Daqui pra frente**.

Eu acredito que o correto seria: **Daqui para a frente**, mas como nós, brasileiros, costumamos encurtar **Para a** em **Pra**. É bem mais prático para escrever e pronunciar. 
Mas é como o comentário acima diz: **Para** requere um objeto direto, para a frente, para atrás..

Comment: Mesmo com o encurtamento, a pergunta mantém-se: "*qual o correto, 'daqui pra frente' ou 'daqui prá frente'?*". Porque "para" encurta de maneira diferente de "para": ao encurtar "para a", os dois "a" aglutinam e **têm** de ganhar um acento, "prá". Como em *a+a>à*, *a+aquilo>àquilo*, *a+aquela>àquela*, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Daqui para frente não existe.

"Daqui pr'á frente" é o resultado na oralidade da contração em linguagem corrente de "Daqui para a frente".

No brasil como a vogal "a" sozinha soa da mesma maneira que "á"(a acentuado) acaba-se por colocar esse tipo de questão que em Portugal não faz tanto sentido.